# QStorageInfo with URL

Tags: c++, qt5

Is there any way to use the `QStorageInfo` class with `URL`s ? I mean I'd like to know the free disk space of

```
QString folder( "\\\\100.200.300.400\\InterestingFolder" );
QStorageInfo info( folder );
auto freeSpace = info.bytesFree();
```

but it returns -1.

EDIT:

What a bout a mounted drive ?

Comment: The documentation says "about the volume mounted at path.", so I would say no, unless you mount it. Don't have an environment to test it though.

Comment: `\\IP-address\Folder` is **not** a URL, but a UNC path. A url looks like `http://example.com/path` and no, you can't get the free disk space of a webserver in that way.

Comment: What about a mounted volume ?